# How to deploy gluon mobile project to iPhone with MacBook

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, gluon, gluon-mobile

We tried to deploy our written App onto an iOS device using a free Apple developer account.
To deploy the project we started with the gradle task "ios", but this always shows a lot of warning and never ends...
Warnings include often "java.awt.*", whereas the star stands for a class name. However, we were only coding in JavaFX, and we checked again if we use any awt classes... and we don't.

We also tried running "launchIPhoneSimulator" and "launchIOSDevice" but with no success at all.

Java SDK version is 1.8_151 and using gluon down 3.6.0, charm down version 2.0.1, javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.8.

MacBook Pro (Early 2015, i7, 16 GB of RAM) High Sierra in combination with iPhone 6 running with iOS 11.0.3.

Any hints on what we are doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated :-)

EDIT: Here is the console output:

```
14:16:29: Executing external task 'ios'...
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:createDefaultIOSLauncher UP-TO-DATE
:compileIosJava UP-TO-DATE
:processIosResources UP-TO-DATE
:iosClasses UP-TO-DATE
:iosExtractNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
:createIpa
Root pattern javax.annotations.**.* matches no classes
Root pattern javax.inject.**.* matches no classes
Warning: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.FileSystem is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.OpenOption is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.FileSystems is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.TimedEvent is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.EventToken is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.ValueDefinition is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.EventDefinition is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.Producer is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder is a phantom class!
Warning: sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer is a phantom class!
Warning: java.util.stream.Stream is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Font is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Graphics2D is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.BufferedImage is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint$CycleMethod is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.AffineTransform is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Path2D is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Line2D is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Color is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Paint is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Stroke is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Rectangle is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Shape is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.AlphaComposite is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.SampleModel is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.DataBufferInt is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.Raster is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.WritableRaster is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.DataBuffer is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Line2D$Float is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.BasicStroke is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.font.GlyphVector is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.LinearGradientPaint is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Point2D$Float is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.font.FontRenderContext is a phantom class!
Warning: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.RenderingHints$Key is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.GradientPaint is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Point2D is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.RenderingHints is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.ImageObserver is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Composite is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Image is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Graphics is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Float is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.TexturePaint is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Float is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.PathIterator is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.PaintContext is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.ColorModel is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.GeneralPath is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Point2D$Double is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.geom.Area is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.PrintService is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.DocFlavor is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.PrintServiceLookup is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.print.PrinterJob is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.SheetCollate is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.Chromaticity is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.OrientationRequested is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterResolution is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.PrintQuality is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.Media is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaTray is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.print.Pageable is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.print.Printable is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.CopiesSupported is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.ResolutionSyntax is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaPrintableArea is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.print.PageFormat is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.PageRanges is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.Attribute is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.Size2DSyntax is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.print.PrinterException is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.print.attribute.standard.DialogTypeSelection is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Transparency is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.image.DirectColorModel is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.print.Paper is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException is a phantom class!
```

https://pastebin.com/VbEQdXyy

EDIT: Solved - If you do have the same problem, follow the steps below in the comments.

Comment: "Never ends" means that the first time you have to run the ahead of time compiler and compile everything (it may take around 20 minutes). After that the next runs should take around a minute. The console output is incomplete, and it doesn't really show an actual error. Let the process finish and post a more complete output.

Comment: We did let it run for half an hour without any result. Back in November last year we did let it run on a MacBook Air for several hours - also for like 4 hours on a really old one. It usually keeps on running until an out of memory exception occurs. What would you suggest or in what way can we provide more information?

Comment: First of all, I'll start with a new template project from the Gluon IDE plugin (i.e single view project, but not the one with Gluon VM). That will contain the latest versions of all the required dependencies. Then I'll try to compile it for iOS. I suggest that you increase the JVM memory to 4GB (`-Xmx4g`). On the mentioned Mac it shouldn't take more than 20 minutes to compile. And if it runs out of memory, try again (the next run will be shorter, all is cached).

Comment: When that works,  you will have to deal with the iOS provisioning. The easiest way is to try first the simulator, as it doesn't require that provisioning. To deploy to an iOS device, you should create an Xcode project first with the same bundle name (same package name), and deploy it: this will install a provisioning profile on the device that it will be used later on when you deploy your app.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you that late, a lot was going on. We tried to increase the JVM memory to 4GB. However, the empty project failed the first time after ~16 minutes: java.lang.outOfMemoryError: Java heap space. After that, we did re-run it, as you suggested, and it failed again, after another 21 minutes: java.lang.outOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. We have now increased the JVM memory to 8GB and are trying again. Do you have any other suggestions meanwhile?

Comment: We've let it run for an hour and three minutes, and it won't go over the "createIPA" step.

Any suggestions on how to proceed or what to try next? :) Thank you!

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro, 2015, same setup. First run takes 20 minutes or so, after that just about 1 or 2 minutes. The IDE plugin should have created a template project with latest dependencies (i.e. jfxmobile 1.3.10 or Down 3.7.2). If you run into any issue please post again your build.gradle file and run with `./gradlew --info createIpa` and post the relevant stacktrace, or the full log as you did before.

Comment: You can find the build.gradle file here: https://pastebin.com/qUFxygjC 
It is unchanged from the start multiview project.

The output of ./gradlew --info createIpa is here: https://pastebin.com/T2cSDc0b

VM options:
-Xmx8g

Comment: In case you don't set properly the VM options: Add this to your `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx4096m -Xss2m`, save and try again.

Comment: Thank you! It worked now for the default Project from Gluon. We tried now the same for our app. Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/LexBqabZ

There is a LOCKDOWN_E_PLIST_ERROR. Do you know how to solve that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have latest Xcode? I'd try to bump the version numbers of your project's dependencies (see template for reference). Also, check if the app was created, maybe you can install it through Xcode (it should be under `/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/*.app`, like [this](http://docs.gluonhq.com/gluonvm/#_deploying_to_iphone_ipad_fails_but_the_app_was_created)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your information! We were able to drag and drop it into XCode and deploy it onto the iPhone :-)
We would like to get rid of the last "drag and drop" step, so could you clearify where we can find the template for the dependencies?
Thank you once again!

Comment: If you use the Gluon plugin on your IDE, create a new mobile project (but not the one using Gluon VM), and check the `build.gradle` generated file, it will have the latest versions available.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Now the deployment is running without any issues :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you hide the most important information from us? The *s might provide a hint of what is going wrong. Some JavaFX classes internally use AWT. For example printing. Do you have anything like this in your code?

Comment: This should be a comment :)

Comment: Our intention was not to hide the information, it is just too much in the console.
But here it is: https://pastebin.com/VbEQdXyy

And yes, we use printing... Is that bad?

Comment: JavaFX printing makes use of AWT and as far as I know this is not supported by the mobile plugin. So try to get rid of this code and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! What would you recommend as alternative? We use "printWriters" to write an export of our app, which can be shared afterwards - obviously it works fine on Android...

Comment: There is nothing in the stacktrace that indicates that AWT is being used. The "stacktrace" is incomplete, and it doesn't really show an actual error.